# AWS S3 Lightsail snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm using the following github script to try to schedule snapshots for a lightsail instance https://github.com/awslabs/lightsail-auto-snapshots

I've run aws configure and added my user's access and secret.  When I do, I get the following:

```
make_bucket failed: s3://temp-lightsail-auto-snapshots-acda7d07b429a8b2 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Access Denied
```

If I go to S3, logged in as myself, I can create buckets all day long.  Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this?  My user has S3 "Full Access" when I look at the permissions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that the IAM role assigned to the user you are using doesn't have rights to S3.

I believe you need the following roles attached to the user's group:

- AWSLambdaRole
- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
- AmazonS3FullAccess

But I've not yet successfully deployed the code so there might be more.